# CMakeLists parse file

Tags: json, xml, parsing, c++11, cmake

I would like to parse a file (XML, JSON or similar) in my CMakeLists and set some variables accordingly.

For example, say I have the following file:

```
<root>
 <Object>
  <name = "my_name"/>
  <url = "my_url"/>
 </Object> 
 <Object>
  <name = "another_name"/>
  <url = "another_url"/>
 </Object> 
</root>
```

and then in my CMakeLists I would like to set a variable with all the names and another variable with all the urls.

Is that possible? I haven't found much on this topic.

Comment: Your example is not valid XML. You could change your example to <name value="another_name"/> or <name>another_name</name>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake does not provide an json or XML parser by itself. However you can use tool like jq or xmlstarlet.
You can call the tools with execute_process or add_custom_command from CMake depending on your needs.

jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

xmlstarlet: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php

Answer (score 35):

As of CMake 3.19, you can use CMake to query and modify JSON strings using the [`string(JSON ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#id2) command.

If you have a JSON file like this:

```
[
   {
      "name": "my_name",
      "url": "my_url"
   },
   {
      "name": "another_name",
      "url": "another_url"
   }
]
```

you can read the file, and create CMake variables containing the names and URLs from the JSON file.

```
# Read the JSON file.
file(READ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myjson.json MY_JSON_STRING)

# Loop through each element of the JSON array (indices 0 though 1).
foreach(IDX RANGE 1)
    # Get the name from the current JSON element.
    string(JSON CUR_NAME GET ${MY_JSON_STRING} ${IDX} name)
    list(APPEND MY_NAMES ${CUR_NAME})
    # Get the URL from the current JSON element.
    string(JSON CUR_URL GET ${MY_JSON_STRING} ${IDX} url)
    list(APPEND MY_URLS ${CUR_URL})
endforeach()

message("MY_NAMES: ${MY_NAMES}")
message("MY_URLS: ${MY_URLS}")
```

This CMake code prints:

```
MY_NAMES: my_name;another_name
MY_URLS: my_url;another_url
```

Comment: `"dir": ["a/b", "c/d" ],` . How should we iterate dir array ?